# Extra spacing above items

Tags: tables, itemize, easylist

I am trying to put list items inside a table. So far everything is fine except the fact that there exists large margin above and below the itemlist. I want to reduce that margin.

I didn't define any table margin anywhere in my tex file (as you can see in the 3rd row of the table where I put plain text, and no margin is visible)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage[sc]{titlesec}
\usepackage[margin=1in, headheight=14.5pt]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{.63,.63,.63}
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Test Table}
\label{timelien}
\begin{center}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
\begin{tabular}{L{3.5cm} L{11cm}}
\hline
\textbf{Period} & \textbf{Project}\\
\hline
Period 1 & 
\begin{easylist}[itemize]
\ListProperties(Margin=0cm)
& Project 1 \& Project 2 \& Project 3
\end{easylist}
\\ \hline
Period 2 & 
\begin{easylist}[itemize]
\ListProperties(Margin=0cm)
& Project 1 \& Project 2 \& Project 3
\end{easylist}
\\ \hline
Period 2 & Test Line
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you going to have more than one item in the row and/or will the item span multiple lines?

Comment: yes actually ... I made a mistake while capturing .. the & in each line actually another item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`easylist` provides `Space` key for this. From manual (page 8):

[image]

So the `\ListProperties(Space*=0cm)` reduces the space above the item. To reduce it below the last item use `\\[<dimension>]` at the end of row.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage[sc]{titlesec}
\usepackage[margin=1in, headheight=14.5pt]{geometry}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{.63,.63,.63}
\begin{table}[ht]
%\ListProperties(Space*=0cm)
\caption{Test Table}
\label{timelien}
\begin{center}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
\begin{tabular}{L{3.5cm} L{11cm}}
\hline
\textbf{Period} & \textbf{Project}\\
\hline
Period 1 &
\begin{easylist}[itemize]
\ListProperties(Margin=0cm,Space*=0cm)
& Project 1 \& Project 2 \& Project 3
\end{easylist}
\\[-5mm] \hline
Period 2 &
\begin{easylist}[itemize]
\ListProperties(Margin=0cm,Space*=0cm)
& Project 1 \& Project 2 \& Project 3
\end{easylist}
\\[-5mm] \hline
Period 2 & Test Line
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another alternative is to place the `easylist` environment inside a `minipage`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage[sc]{titlesec}
\usepackage[margin=1in, headheight=14.5pt]{geometry}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\arrayrulecolor[rgb]{.63,.63,.63}
\begin{table}[ht]
%\ListProperties(Space*=0cm)
\caption{Test Table}
\label{timelien}
\begin{center}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
\begin{tabular}{L{3.5cm} L{11cm}}
\hline
\textbf{Period} & \textbf{Project}\\
\hline
Period 1 &
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{easylist}[itemize]
\ListProperties(Margin=0cm)
& Project 1 \& Project 2 \& Project 3
\end{easylist}
\end{minipage}
\\ \hline
Period 2 &
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{easylist}[itemize]
\ListProperties(Margin=0cm)
& Project 1 \& Project 2 \& Project 3
\end{easylist}
\end{minipage}
\\ \hline
Period 2 & Test Line
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

If you don't want to type `negin{minipage}...` etc for every `easylist` environment, add the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{easylist}{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{easylist}{\end{minipage}}
```

But this will be applicable to all `easylist` environments.

Comment: One issue of using \\[<dimension>] is that it just shift the line, not the text. So the vertical alignment distorts. For example, if I put vertical alignment as middle, and use \\[-5mm], the text in the first column won't be in the middle anymore (let say I have multiple list items in 2nd column).

Comment: @AbdFahim: See the edit for an alternative.